# Restrict data in the ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

Please let me know if there's something wrong with my approach.
I have a WPF window which contains a datagrid. This is for the users to input a list of object IDs for the program to process.

I am binding the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection, where MyObject is a class with a single string property - ObjectId.

I have an event for when collection is changed:

```
 void TasksList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBarMax = TasksList.Count;
            TaskCountLabel = string.Format("{0} tasks to modify", TasksList.Count);
        }
```

I would also like to validate the data on input - the user might provide an incorrect Id, in which case I don't want to add it to the collection.
However, when I access the e.NewItems[0] object, its ObjectId property is still null, so I cannot validate.

What is wrong with my approach?

Adding datagrid XAML as per comments:

```
<DataGrid Margin="5,0,5,10"
                                         ColumnWidth="*"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisUc,
                                                               Path=TasksList,
                                                               Mode=TwoWay,
                                                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                         Style="{x:Null}"
                                         CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserPasteToNewRows="True"
                                         x:Name="TasksDataGrid"
                                         CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         SelectionUnit="Cell" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to perform this validation **before** it is added to the collection instead of after. How are you currently adding items to this collection? An `ICommand`?

Comment: @MikeEason - No... the collection is bound to the datagrid, so it gets updated when a user starts typing in the datagrid cell...

Comment: Post your datagrid xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would also like to validate the data on input

Just use WPF validation capabilities.  E.g., [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-based validation:

```
public class RowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // INPC implementation is omitted

    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string id;

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
            {
                return "Id cannot be an empty string.";
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

> the user might provide an incorrect Id, in which case I don't want to
>   add it to the collection

You can't.

When `DataGrid` uses in-place editing, adding new row automatically adds new item into the bound `ItemsSource`. But if the row data source uses validation, user can't commit changes until there are validation errors.

In this case user has one way to go - to cancel editing, and when he cancels, `DataGrid` removes new row from the underlying `ItemsSource`.